# Today + have had or today + had?

Tags: grammaticality

When you meet an individual for the first time, would you say

> Today I had the pleasure to meet him

or

> Today I have had the pleasure to meet him

?

Answer (score 0):

Use "have had" if he is still there with you. If he has left (or if you have left), then use "had".

Comment: Neither, Larisa; not with “pleasure to…”

“I had / have had the pleasure of meeting…” or “took pleasure in meeting…” or “It gave me pleasure / I was pleased to meet…”

His being there makes no difference; time will

“Today / Yesterday / I had the pleasure of meeting…” succeed

“Today / I have had…” succeed

“Yesterday I have had the pleasure of meeting…” fails

(anyone who wants to fill in the tenses please feel free)